# Starting Groovy/Grails Tool Suite fails with internal error: `Requesting Java AST from selection`

Tags: eclipse, ggts

Hello when I launch my Eclipse(Groovy/Grails Tool Suite™ (GGTS) - Spring) i get this error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from
>   selection". Unresolved compilation problems:     The import
>   grails.util cannot be resolved    CollectionUtils cannot be resolved
>   org.springframework cannot be resolved to a type
>   org.springframework cannot be resolved to a type
>   org.springframework cannot be resolved to a type

And when I try to update my plugins dependencies I just get and error and nothing is updated. Can anyone please help.

I have GGTS and this message is poping up each time I click on eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite™ (GGTS) - Spring An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366581/groovy-grails-tool-suite%e2%84%a2-ggts-spring-an-internal-error-occurred-during-re)

Comment: If no one is able to anwer here, maybe you should file a bug with the vendor of this software?

Comment: I just changed the question. perhaps someone else has faced this issue before. i'll need to know which way to go to get this thing sorted out